# ios 8 uiimagepicker camera orientation issue

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8

I have iPad application and i use it to take pictures.
I use UIImagePicker and everything worked out fine until iOS8.

on iOS8 - the camera view of the picker opens up fine (no matter what orientation i am on), but when i rotate the device, the camera view remains on the original orientation (only scaled). moreover - if i turn the device up-side-down than i the camera is up-side-down too.

Any ideas? at start i thought it is a beta issue, but now i see it happens on the GM Release too.
I saw it on applications like Google Drive also.

very strange..

EDIT: happens on iOS 8.0.2 too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered it on different thread:

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336898/2134838)

in a couple of words:

1. It's an apple bug
2. there is a patch to fix it for now

EDIT: fixed in iOS 8.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Using Xamaring iOS, you must override the UIImagePickerController to return false on the should autorotate function. I assume that there is an objective c equivalent.

```
    public class UIImagePickerWithoutRotation : UIImagePickerController
    {
        public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```